# Create custom button animations on android

Tags: android, animation, imagebutton

I have an imagebutton which I want to animate when it changes drawable. I want to animate the movement from the [pencil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1H2B.png) to the [cross](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLLHk.png) much like the hamburger changes to a back arrow when the drawer is opened. I apologise the images are white which is the same as the background (the only version I have of them) so simply drag the image from the link and you will see what I mean. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to getting started with this.

Comment: What kind of animation you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an animated icon using AnimatedDrawable and bitmap-based frames. On L, you can use AnimatedStateListDrawable to create stateful animations (such as the check box animation).

Here is an AnimatedDrawable example (actually this is the implementation for the check box on L preview) using 15ms-long frames that can be started and stopped from code:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/my_icon_frame_000" />
    ...additional frames...
</animation-list>
```

And here is an AnimatedStateListDrawable using AnimatedDrawable transitions to implement a check box animation that starts and stops automatically based on View state:

```
<animated-selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_checked="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015" android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" android:alpha="?attr/disabledAlpha" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000" android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal" android:alpha="?attr/disabledAlpha" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:id="@+id/on">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015" android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/off">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000" android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal" />
    </item>
    <transition android:fromId="@+id/off" android:toId="@+id/on">
        <animation-list>
            <item android:duration="15">
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000" android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal" />
            </item>
            ...additional frames...
        </animation-list>
    </transition>
    <transition android:fromId="@+id/on" android:toId="@+id/off">
        <animation-list>
            <item android:duration="15">
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/btn_check_to_off_mtrl_000" android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" />
            </item>
            ...additional frames...
        </animation-list>
    </transition>
</animated-selector>
```

credit: [Android L "delightful" drawable transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371958/android-l-delightful-drawable-transformations)

For further information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html